# UPDATE mysql_query not updating table

Tags: php, mysql

Im having trouble with the UPDATE command.

Im trying to update my db but its just not happening. Ive been trying to get this to work for the last 10 days and its driving me nuts.

Here is the code:

```
$a = mysql_query("UPDATE `findacab` SET `lat` = ".$ads['Latitude']." , `long` = ".$ads['Longitude']."
                WHERE `eeventendtime` = ".$ads['Postcode']."  ");
```

Table:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT Postcode, Latitude, Longitude FROM postcodes");
while($ads = mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
{ 
    mysql_query("UPDATE findacab SET lat = '".$ads['Latitude']."' , long = '".$ads['Longitude']."' WHERE eeventendtime = '".$ads['Postcode']."' ");
    echo $ads['Latitude']." ".$ads['Longitude']." ".$ads['Postcode']."</br>";
     //$query = "select count(*) from findacab where eeventendtime = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ads['Postcode'])."'"; 
}
```

Comment: What does mysql_error() say? What's the final output of that $sql variable? Is it correct? Have you run it in a tool like phpmyadmin?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: You probably need to quote those SQL values: `SET lat='".$ads['Lattitude']."', long='".$ads['Longitude']."'` ... etc.

Comment: 1. what error(s) are you getting? 2. what is your table schema? 3. use mysqli or pdo function sets as the mysql ones are deprecated.

Comment: Can you post the structure of the findacab table and also confirm that  eeventendtime = ".$ads['Postcode']." evaluates as true.

Comment: what data type are you using for lat and long? if you use strings, you should have single quotes arround values.

Comment: eeventendtime - double e?

Comment: Here is where the code is running. programmer.mobi/jsone5.php

Comment: POST THE TABLE STRUCTURE, it has only been asked like 10 times. We are just guessing for you. It is not helping you nor us

Comment: sorry, ive been out at work.

Comment: Sorry, the update is working. The problem is the file is so big it takes a very long time to update all the postcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your complete table consists of only integer you should add quotations around your strings

```
$a = mysql_query("UPDATE `findacab` SET 
    `lat` = '".$ads['Latitude']."' , 
    `long` = '".$ads['Longitude']."' 
    WHERE 
    `eeventendtime` = '".$ads['Postcode']."' ");
```

Comment: Its not just integer so i have changed the code and added  ' '

Comment: The lat long in the findacab table is not being updated with the lat long values in the postcodes table.

Comment: please post table structures of those tables and part of the script that defines the $ads

Comment: $q = mysql_query("SELECT Postcode, Latitude, Longitude FROM postcodes");

while($ads = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{

mysql_query("UPDATE `findacab` SET `lat` = '".$ads['Latitude']."' , `long` = '".$ads['Longitude']."'
                    WHERE `eeventendtime` = '".$ads['Postcode']."' ");
echo  $ads['Latitude']." ".$ads['Longitude']." ".$ads['Postcode']."</br>";


}

Comment: @user2105721: `$q=...` is NOT the table structure.  You get the table structure with `DESCRIBE mytable`.

Comment: You can see an image of the database structure here: programmer.mobi/img1.png

Comment: Sorry, the update is working. The problem is the file is so big it takes a very long time to update all the postcodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select count(*) from findacab where eeventendtime = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ads['Postcode'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0]
```

If it returns 0 then you just don't have records to update.
Another possible reason - you are trying to update table with same values as stored. In this case update will not change the data.